# How do I verify that an integer value within a large number in a certain position is a certain value in Java?

Tags: java

I've searched all over and saw different variances.  But neither seemed to work for me :(  So in Java how can I check the value of a certain position of large integer?  I want to have a check to ensure that the 1st position in any number like 678954 is a value of 4.  What built in Java class is there to check the value of an integer within an certain position?  I would assume there is something built in like .charAt for this?  Like below I want to ensure the 1st position in the integer is a '0'.  If I missed a previous answer to this same question that has happened before please excuse me.  If so could you post the link from it in Stackoverflow? Oh I saw something about Character.getNumericValue, I tried that and got the same "int can not be dereferenced" error.

if(getEmployeeId().charAt(0) == '0')

Cheers!

Comment: just convert the int to string (base 10) and use chatAt

Comment: `int` is a basic type not a `class` it does not have methods, you can do `Integer i = new Integer(int_value)` if you need access to the methods defined in `java.lang.Integer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in java integers are stored in binary. For example the number 678954 would be 10100101110000101010.

As you can see *10100101110000101010* does not have a character '4' inside of it. What you should do instead is to convert the integer to string so that you do string operations on it.

An easy way to do this is to use the **Integer.toString(aInt)** to convert your integers to strings first.

try changing your code from

`if(getEmployeeId().charAt(0) == '0')`

to

`if(Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '0')`

Comment: Ok thanks I'm going to give this as the answer..as it would help others with the breakdown of how you described it.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

```
String str = Integer.toString(getEmployeeId());
if(str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == '0')
```

Or, with mod,

```
if (getEmployeeId % 10 == 0)
```

Comment: Ok thank you Louis.  Ok so the only way is to convert it to a String and use the length class to verify the count, interesting.  Okay so the "-1" I assume is because the "length" class doesn't count the "zero" position? So doing the -1 sets it at the zero position boss?

Comment: You asked about the _last_ character.  Strings are zero-indexed from left to right, so the last character is at `str.length() - 1`.

Comment: Ok gotcha the base is 10.  And the last position would be nine..which is where the minus 1 comes in @.  Ok I see now, I'll go with that one.  Thanks Louis!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply your math skills and use `/` and `%` to check digits of a number without converting it to a string:

```
if (num % 10 == 4) {
    // The last digit is 4
}

if ((num/1000) % 10 == 7) {
    // Digit at position 4 is 7
}
```

The idea is to "shift" the decimal representation of the number by dividing it by a power of ten, and then get the last digit by computing the remainder after division by ten.

Comment: +1 for doing this the simple way (without doing string conversions).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, check out @Louis Wassermans answer. you need to convert an int to a string first in order to check the value using charAt(). I don't think charAt() works with ints.